# Coordinates to svg map

Tags: cartography, coordinates, svg

I have a large list of Lambert coordinates. All those points connected create different area from a country.

I would like to have this map as a SVG path (each region would have its path).

I cannot find any way to do this. I only land on websites that offer the possibility to translate my Lambert coords in GPS coordinates.

Is there any tools that can translate coordinates to SVG ?

See below the final map (without the markers)
[image]

Comment: I was about to add is answer but @iant marked it as duplicate, in summary you can use QGIS to convert points to polygons then install a plugin called **SimpleSVG** from plugin managers in QGIS to export your view to SVG.

Comment: @Shady as iant said, you can answer the original question.